# Combining many columns in R at once

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe that looks somewhat like the following:

```
A1U_sweet  A2F_dip  A3U_bbq  C1U_sweet  C2F_dip  C3U_bbq
1          2        1        NA         NA       NA
NA         NA       NA       4          1        2
2          4        7        NA         NA       NA
```

I would like to make additional columns that combine the A values and the C values. The resulting dataframe would include columns looking like B1U_sweet and B2F_dip.

```
A1U_sweet  A2F_dip  A3U_bbq  C1U_sweet  C2F_dip  C3U_bbq  B1U_sweet  B2F_dip
1          2        1        NA         NA       NA       1          2
NA         NA       NA       4          1        2        4          1
2          4        7        NA         NA       NA       2          4
```

Is there a way for me to create these additional columns without combining the A and C columns one by one? In the past I've combined them each individually, but it would be great if there were something like a loop that matched columns A1 and C1, A2 and C2, etc. There are 20 "A" columns and 20 "C" columns that I would like to combine into "B" columns.

EDIT: The solution is the accepted answer here: [Combining columns in R based on matching beginnings of column title names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713927/combining-columns-in-r-based-on-matching-beginnings-of-column-title-names)

Comment: I'm not sure how you're "combining" the columns, but you could try: `res <- mapply(sum, df[, 1:3], df[, 4:6], na.rm=T)`. Replace the 1:3 and 4:6 with a character vector of names if there is a clever way of parsing the names out. Right now, `grep('A', colnames(df))` and `grep('C', colnames(df))` works.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
types <- grep('^A', names(df)) ## Get all "A" patterns
types <- substr(types, 2, Inf) ## Remove the "A"
for (tp in types) {
  aa <- df[[paste0('A', tp)]] ## "A" column
  cc <- df[[paste0('C', tp)]] ## "C" column
  df[[paste0('B', tp)]] <- ifelse(is.na(aa), aa, cc)
}
```

EDIT: If some other columns in your df start with A, you can try one of 3 things:

1. Remove them from the df first
2. Don't grep the types, but rather manually input them (e.g. `types <- c("1U_sweet", ...)`
3. If your types follow a specific pattern, you could change the regex in grep to something like `"^A[0-9][0-9][A-Z]_[a-z]+"`

Comment: Is it an issue if there are other columns in the dataframe that begin with A or C? For example, I have an Age column and a Comments column and am worried they would interfere.

Comment: What does each component in the "^A[0-9][A-Z]_[a-z]+" mean?

Comment: It means it starts with upper case A, then a number, then any one capital letter, then underscore, then one or more lower case letters

Comment: Some of the values where it is currently [0-9] go up to 20. For example, there are column names beginning A13F_cr and A20U_kj. I tried changing the [0-9] to [0-20] but it did not work. How do I account for this?

Comment: Also, the "a" from is.na(a) triggered an error. "Object 'a' not found". Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `aa`, not `a`. I changed the names to aa and cc to avoid overwriting the c() function.

Comment: And about the numbers up to 20, [0-9] means one digit, so [0-9][0-9] means 2 digits (i.e. it could go up to 99). If you only want it to go up to 20, it can be done but is more complex: "([0-9]|[12][0-9])", which means "either (i) a digit between 0 and 9, OR (ii) (1 or 2) and a digit between 0 and 9"

Comment: What does the 1 or 2 mean in the [12]? I tried ^A[0-9]|[12][0-9][A-Z]_[a-z]+ in grep and it's still not pulling what it should pull.

Comment: That's not what I said. You forgot the parentheses. `"^A([0-9]|[12][0-9])[A-Z]_[a-z]+"`. In general, "[]" means any character (not strings of characters) within here, so "[a1]" does *not* mean "a1", but rather "an a or a 1". Therefore, "[12]" means a 1 or a 2

Comment: Also, please note writing regular expressions is hard when you don't have full visibility of what you want them to do. You can get as broad or as specific as you want, but you need to know what you really want.

Comment: Ah sorry! The first part works now but when I run the "for" function (which I copied and pasted to avoid errors) I get this error: Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, paste0("B", tp), value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 94
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(aa) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL' . Do you know why this might be? (Also, thank you so much for your help!)

Comment: It probably means you have the "A" variable, but it is NA, and the "C" variable is not present. This is why you might be better off writing the patterns by hand.

Comment: The accepted answer here is another solution in case you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713927/combining-columns-in-r-based-on-matching-beginnings-of-column-title-names/48714484#48714484

Comment: That approach will have problems with your other variables starting with A. Otherwise it also works

Answer (score 0):

A dplyr approach without using loops:

```
df = read.table(text = "
A1U_sweet  A2F_dip  A3U_bbq  C1U_sweet  C2F_dip  C3U_bbq
1          2        1        NA         NA       NA
NA         NA       NA       4          1        2
2          4        7        NA         NA       NA
", header=T)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(col,value,-row_id) %>%
  mutate(col1 = substr(col, 1, 1),
         col2 = substr(col, 2, nchar(col))) %>%
  group_by(row_id, col2) %>%
  summarise(new_value = unique(value[!is.na(value)])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(col2 = paste0("B",col2)) %>%
  spread(col2,new_value) %>%
  bind_cols(df) %>%
  select(-row_id, -B3U_bbq)

# # A tibble: 3 x 8
#   B1U_sweet B2F_dip A1U_sweet A2F_dip A3U_bbq C1U_sweet C2F_dip C3U_bbq
#       <int>   <int>     <int>   <int>   <int>     <int>   <int>   <int>
# 1         1       2         1       2       1        NA      NA      NA
# 2         4       1        NA      NA      NA         4       1       2
# 3         2       4         2       4       7        NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: If you spot any bugs when you try to apply this in your full dataset let me know and I'll be able to update it. Based on your example I assumed the column names will always start from A or C and that there will always be a single non NA value across sweet, dip, etc. at each row.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what each row does? Also, the column names in my actual dataframe are not column 1, column 2 etc. as in the example. The A names begin in column 19 and the C names begin in column 39 (there are 20 A names and 20 corresponding C names). What would I modify to account for this?