# Reorganizing dataframe with multiple header types following "tidy" approach in R

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that looks like somewhat like this:

```
Age  A1U_sweet  A2F_dip  A3U_bbq  C1U_sweet  C2F_dip  C3U_bbq  Comments
23   1          2        1        NA         NA       NA       Good
54   NA         NA       NA       4          1        2        ABCD
43   2          4        7        NA         NA       NA       HiHi
```

I am trying to reorganize it in way shown below to make it more "tidy". Is there a way for me to do this that also incorporates the Age and Comments columns in the same style as shown for the other variables below? How would you suggest incorporating them - one idea is shown below, but I am open to other suggestions. How would I modify the following code in order to account for multiple different styles of column name?

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(id = 1:nrow(df), df)
dfl <- gather(df, key = "key", value = "value", -id)
dfl <- separate(dfl, key, into = c("key", "kind", "type"), sep = c(1, 4))
df2 <- spread(dfl, key, value)
df2
##   id kind  type     A    C
## 1  1  Age   Age    23   23
## 2  1  1U_ sweet     1   NA
## 3  1  2F_   dip     2   NA
## 4  1  3U_   bbq     1   NA
## 5  1  Com   Com  Good Good
## 6  2  Age   Age    54   54
## 7  2  1U_ sweet    NA    4
## 8  2  2F_   dip    NA    1
## 9  2  3U_   bbq    NA    2
##10  2  Com   Com  ABCD ABCD
##11  3  Age   Age    43   43
##12  3  1U_ sweet     2   NA
##13  3  2F_   dip     4   NA
##14  3  3U_   bbq     7   NA
##15  3  Com   Com  HiHi HiHi
```

And how would I modify the following code to return the data back to how it originally was?

```
df <- gather(df2, key = "key", value = "value", A, B, C)
df <- unite(df, "key", key, kind, type, sep = "")
df <- spread(df, key, value)
```

For context, this question was prompted by Ista's comment under this question: [Combining columns in R based on matching beginnings of column title names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713927/combining-columns-in-r-based-on-matching-beginnings-of-column-title-names/48716608?noredirect=1#comment84433560_48716608)

Comment: Where do you have `age` and `comments` in yoru data? I do not understand what you are saying. Could you clarify that?

Comment: As @jazzurro mentioned, it is not clear about the `age` and `sweets`.  Please update your example with expected output

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work as desired?

Comment: Better refine your question. Asking the community to comment on data not included in your example is poor etiquette.

Comment: I have updated the dataframe to reflect these comments. I've also included a link to the question that has Ista's comment that inspired this question originally. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You have not understood the basic concepts. You must learn to think in terms of the **unit of observation** and **measurements**. Start by reading http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf and ask questions here only when you get stuck. Do not expect people to spoon feed you answers that will come naturally if you would only take the time to learn the basics.

Comment: Thanks for the PDF. I will read through it. I assure you I would not have asked a question here if I thought I could have figured it out myself. I would appreciate any other recommendations in addition to that paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Age` and `Comments` are presumably measured at the level of whatever a row in your original data is, just bring them along for the ride:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:nrow(df), df)

dfl <- gather(df, key = "key", value = "value", -id, -Age, -Comments)
dfl <- separate(dfl, key, into = c("key", "kind", "type"), sep = c(1, 4))
df2 <- spread(dfl, key, value)
df2

df2 <- transform(df2, B = ifelse(is.na(A), C, A))
df2

df <- gather(df2, key = "key", value = "value", A, B, C)
df <- unite(df, "key", key, kind, type, sep = "")
df <- spread(df, key, value)
df
```